# Initialize array variable in structure

Tags: c++

I ended up doing like this,

```
struct init
{
    CHAR Name[65];
};

void main()
{
    init i;

    char* _Name = "Name";

    int _int = 0;

    while (_Name[_int] != NULL)
    {
        i.Name[_int] = _Name[_int];
        _int++;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that how you intialize it?

Comment: In C++ main() must return an int, and names like _Name reserved for the C++ implementation's use.

Comment: Pelase indent your code. I'm feeling dizzy.

Comment: Note: _Name is a compiler-reserved identifier, due to the leading underscore; so is _int.

Comment: Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier/228797#228797

Comment: @xtofl: _int is not reserved at function scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give your structure  a constructor:

```
struct init
{
  char Name[65];
  init( const char * s ) {
     strcpy( Name, s );
  }
};
```

Now you can say:

```
init it( "fred" );
```

Even without a constructor, you can initialise it:

```
init it = { "fred" };
```

Comment: Upvoted but I'd be happier with strncpy :)

Comment: +1, I liked the idea of constructor.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, a struct can have a constructor, just like a class. Move the initialization code to the constructor. Also consider using a std::string instead of the char array.

```
struct init
{
    std::string name;

    init (const std::string &n) : name (n)
    {
    }
};
```

Comment: I wish i could but it's one of the defined API structure i was working with.

Comment: @Dave17 Why couldn't you have made that clear in your question? Why do we always have to prise information out of you?

Comment: i'm sorry, won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [strcpy()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) to copy your string data into the char array.

```
strcpy(i.Name, "Name");
```